# Magento External Database Connection - Error

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, plugin

Hi so I am trying to add in a connection to another database in Magento so I can query it, I have done the following:

Made a module and this is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <externaldb_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>externaldb_database</use>
                </connection>
            </externaldb_write>
            <externaldb_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>externaldb_database</use>
                </connection>
            </externaldb_read>
            <externaldb_setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </externaldb_setup>
            <externaldb_database>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[IPADDRESS]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[USERNAME]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[PASSWORD]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[DATABASE]]></dbname>
                    <model>mysql4</model>
                    <type>pdo_mysql</type>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </externaldb_database>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

And this is my code frontend:

```
<?php
  $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
  $conn         = $resource->getConnection('externaldb_read');
  $results  = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM tablename');
  print_r($results);
?>

And I get the following error:
a:5:{i:0;s:125:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'admin_magento_t.tablename' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT * FROM tablename";i:1;s:3026:"#0 /SERVERPATH/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
```

I am confused why it says table "admin_magento_t.tablename" doesnt exist when I am only looking for "tablename"? I have tried this connection manually in PHP and it connects to the database fine

Can someone advise me on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how i use external DB.

**Config.**

```
<resources>
       <customcms_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Test_Magewordpress</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </customcms_setup>
        <externaldb_write>
            <connection>
                <use>externaldb_database</use>
            </connection>
        </externaldb_write>
        <externaldb_read>
            <connection>
                <use>externaldb_database</use>
            </connection>
        </externaldb_read>
     <externaldb_database>
            <connection>
                <host><![CDATA[192.168.0.200]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[test]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[test]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[test_wp]]></dbname>
                <model>mysql4</model>
                <type>pdo_mysql</type>
                <active>1</active>
            </connection>
        </externaldb_database>
    </resources>
```

**connection made through below code successfully**

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('externaldb_read');
    $connection->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp6r_posts WHERE post_type = 'page' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_date DESC";
    $rows = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
```